# How to make use of URL that was saved in cookie?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I am saving a URL in a cookie using Angular

`$cookies.put("targetURL": "http://partners.api.xyz.net/apiservices/deeplink/v2?_cje=TmvlUQgTj%2fbxOQ%2bkXy5haJR9JWcHT9aaSjEP%2fEbwSq4uZqOYt%2fRV9FYsU1PT80PD&url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.apideeplink.com%26cabin_class%3deconomy%26facilitated%3dfalse%26ticket_price%3d72.82%26is_npt%3dfalse%26is_multipart%3dfalse%26client_id%3d2017-02-22T10%3a02%3a07")`

However, I have to retrieve this cookie with plain javascript. When I try to get it, the string is transformed into

"`http%3A%2F%2Fpartners.api.xyz.net%2Fapiservices%2Fdeeplink%2Fv2%3F_cje%3DTmvlUQgTj%252fbxOQ%252bkXy5haJR9JWcHT9aaSjEP%252fEbwSq4uZqOYt%252fRV9FYsU1PT80PD%26url%3Dhttp%253a%252f%252fwww.apideeplink.com%2526cabin_class%253deconomy%2526facilitated%253dfalse%2…e%2526is_multipart%253dfalse%2526client_id%253d2017-02-22T10%253a02%253a07`" and not clickable anymore.

To retrieve the cookie I am using the function:

```
function getCookie(name) {
  var value = "; " + document.cookie;
  var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
  if (parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
}
```

Why is the string changed like this and what can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to decode the URI with `decodeURIComponent()`

```
old = "http%3A%2F%2F";
new = decodeURIComponent( old );

#new => http://
```